# Pass object id thought nested forms in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I am using loop in nested forms in rails and i wanted to pass object id through render partial form

**app/model/contract_booking_attached_trips.rb**

```
class ContractBookingAttachedTrip < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :contract_attached_trip_sheets
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :contract_attached_trip_sheets ,allow_destroy: true
 belongs_to :booking_history
 belongs_to :duty_type
 belongs_to :vehicle_make
 belongs_to :vehicle_category
end
```

**app/model/contract_attached_trip_sheet.rb**

```
class ContractAttachedTripSheet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contract_booking_attached_trip
end
```

**app/controller/contract_booking_attached_trips_controller**

```
 def edit
   @contract_booking_attached_trip = ContractBookingAttachedTrip.find(params[:id])
   booking_history_id = @contract_booking_attached_trip.booking_history_id
   @booking_history  = BookingHistory.find(booking_history_id)
   @booking_trips = @booking_history.transport_plans
   @trip_count = @booking_history.transport_plans.count    
   @contract_booking_attached_trip.contract_attached_trip_sheets.build
end
```

**app/views/ContractBookingAttachedTrips/_form.html.erb**

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <%= form_for(@contract_booking_attached_trip, :html => {class: "form-horizontal",id:              "contract_trip_sheet_validate"}) do |f| %>
 <div class="card">
     <div class="card-header">
     <h5 class="panel-title float-left" style="padding-top: 7.5px;">Duty Slip</h5          
     </div> <!-- /.card header -->
  <div class="card-body">

      <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body" style="margin-bottom: -50px;">

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 mb-4 mb-lg-4">
          <div class="table-responsive ">
        <!--Table-->
        <table id="dataTable" class="table table-borderless  table-sm" cellspacing="0">
          <!--Table body-->
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>Customer</th>
              <th><b><%= User.find(@contract_booking_attached_trip.booking_history.try(:user_id)).try(:username) %></b></th>                         
            </tr>                       
          </tbody>
          <!--Table body-->
        </table>
        <!--Table-->
      </div> <!-- table  -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 mb-4 mb-lg-4">
          <div class="table-responsive ">
        <!--Table-->

      </div> <!-- table  -->
        </div>           
       </div><!-- row1 -->
     </div> <!-- inner card body -->
    </div> <!-- inner card -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h6 class="float-left">Trip Sheet</h6>
               </div> 
           <div class="card-body">

          <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-11">
        <% @booking_history.transport_plans.each do |transport_plan| %>

        <%= f.fields_for :contract_attached_trip_sheets ,transport_plan do |builder| %>   
        <h3><%= transport_plan.id %> </h3>
         <%= render 'contract_attached_trip_sheet_fields', f: builder, transport_plan: transport_plan  %>
        <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </div>

    <div class="col-md-1">
      <%= link_to_add_association "+",  f, :contract_attached_trip_sheets, class: "fa fa-user fa-lg"  %>
       </div> 
       </div>      
         </div> <!-- /.inner card body -->
         </div>    <!-- /.inner card -->
        </div> <!-- /. col 12 -->
      </div> <!-- /.inner card row -->
       </div>       
         </div>
             <div class="card-footer ">
                <div class="btn-group float-right">            
                         <%= f.submit "submit", class:"btn btn-primary btn-sm button",     id:"generateInvoice" %>
                </div>
               </div>

              </div><!-- /.card -->

           <% end %>
            </div> <!-- /.container fluid -->
```

**app/views/contract_booking_attached_trips/_contract_attached_trip_sheet_fields.html.erb**

```
  <fieldset>

   <div class="nested-fields">

     <div class="row">
     <%= transport_plan %>
        <div class="col-md-2">
         <label  class="label" for="">Initial Odo Reading<span class="star"></span></label>
                  <div class="md-form form-group">
                 <%= f.text_field :initial_odo_reading, class: "form-control" %>

                  </div>
                </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
      <label  class="label" for=""> Trip Start Date<span class="star"></span></label>
                  <div class="md-form form-group">
                    <%= f.text_field :trip_start_date_time, class: "form-control"%>

                  </div>
                </div>

<div class="col-md-2">
<label  class="label" for=""> Final Odo Reading<span class="star"></span></label>
                  <div class="md-form form-group">
                    <%= f.text_field :final_odo_reading, class: "form-control" %>
                  </div>
                </div>


 <div class="col-md-2">
<label  class="label" for=""> Trip Stop Date<span class="star"></span></label>
                  <div class="md-form form-group">

                    <%= f.text_field :trip_stop_date_time,  class: "mobile form-control" %>

                  </div>
                </div>



      <div class="col-md-2">
 <label class="label" for=""> Toll Cost<span class="star"></span></label>
                  <div class="md-form form-group">
                    <%= f.text_field :toll_cost, class: "form-control", placeholder:"" %>

                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
 <label class="label" for=""> Permit Cost<span class="star"></span></label>
                  <div class="md-form form-group">
                    <%= f.text_field :permit_cost, class: "form-control", placeholder:"" %>

                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
 <label class="label" for="">Parking Cost<span class="star"></span></label>
                  <div class="md-form form-group">
                    <%= f.text_field :parking_cost, class: "form-control", placeholder:"" %>

                  </div>
                </div>
            <%= f.hidden_field :transport_plan_id, value: transport_plan %>


<div class="col-md-1">
    <br/>


    <%= link_to_remove_association " " ,f, class:"fa fa-trash ", style: "color:red; font-size:20px; top:14px; " %>
                        </div>                    


 </div>
  <br />
   </div>
     </fieldset>
```

i am tryinh to pass transport_plan_id in hidden field but am gettting the following error in 
 [image]

please tell me how to pass the id through nested render partial

Answer (score 0):

In your  `_form` you write

```
<%= render 'contract_attached_trip_sheet_fields', :f => builder,{ :transport_plan =>transport_plan} %>
```

and that should be

```
<%= render 'contract_attached_trip_sheet_fields', :f => builder, :transport_plan =>transport_plan %>
```

There are two ways to pass data to partials, either you write:

```
  render  partial:  'partial_name', locals: {f: builder, a: 123}
```

or the simple form is just

```
  render 'partial_name', f: builder, transport_plan: transport_plan
```

Comment: Thank  You for your reply, I updated my code but still i am getting same error in partial form

Comment: You edited your code, but not the error? In the partial `_contract_attached_trip_sheet_fields` is `transport_plan` still not defined? Please give us the exact error. Why do you iterate over `@booking_history. contract_attached_trip_sheets` instead of just writing `f.fields_for : contract_attached_trip_sheets` which would iterate over the nested items for your main form object?

Comment: <%= render 'contract_attached_trip_sheet_fields', f: builder, transport_plan: transport_plan  %> I am defining transport_plan hear and                                             I am calling <%= transport_plan %> in partial form for verification(i am trying to print transport_plan_id in partial form) .                                                                   @booking_history has many transport_plans i am trying to display number of nested forms as number of transport_plans.

Comment: I am afraid I am unable to express myself clearly. When you write `transport_plan_id`, I hope you mean `transport_plan.id`, right? The iteration over `@booking_history.contract_attached_trip_sheets` will mess up your nested form imho, but it should define `transport_plan` correctly (I hope). Do you have a github repo for me to take a look and try it out?

Comment: Yes I wanted to display transport_plan.id in partial form, I am not using @booking_history.contract_attached_trip_sheets, I am trying to iterate booking_history.transport_plans.

Comment: Okay, it is obvious I do not understand your code: you edit a `ContractBookingAttachedTrip`, which `has_many :contract_attached_trip_sheets`, but you iterate over `@booking.transport_plans` and save them to that association? Colour me confused. You do not explain that, and the overload on information only confuses me. You should try to minimise the example to focus on what the error might be. Anyway, I will delete this, as it obvious I do not understand your question correctly, and you are not taking any steps to make it clearer.